# How to apply a user-specified criteria to multiple fields in an Access query?

Tags: sql, database, parameters, ms-access-2007, criteria

I'm working in Access 2007.  I want make a query where the user is prompted to enter a date, and the date they enter becomes the criteria for multiple date fields in the query.  I only want them to have to enter the date once, not once for each field.  Is this possible?  How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a query parameter that will be used in several places then you should declare it in the Parameters dialog within the Access query builder

[image: Ribbon.png]

In there you can define the parameter's "name" (which is also the prompt text) and data type.

[image: ParamDialog.png]

Once that is done, Access recognizes the parameter and offers it in IntelliSense prompts when building the rest of the query:

[image: IntelliSense.png]

When the user runs the query they will only be prompted to "Enter the Start Date:" once, even if that parameter is used in multiple places within the query.

Comment: Agreed, but I still think a form is better.

Comment: EXCELLENT, that does exactly what I need.  I'll have to explore this feature more.  Can't thank you enough Gord!